# How to enable scrolling for a ListView inside ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-scrollview, touch-event

First off - I know you shouldn't be doing that and unless you have a viable point please don't comment on that matter. I am somehow forced by the layout to use such a design (look at the image).

[image: layout]

I already tried

```
mListView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
            {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
                {
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    return false;
                }

            });
```

but the ListView doesn't seem to even receive the TouchEvent before it's intercepted - I tested it and when I set the same OnTouchListener in the horizontal LinearLayout it works and suppresses the interception, but the same thing on the ListView doesn't work.

Do you have any ideas how to fix it? I suspect a headerView won't suffice here, will it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ListView inside a ScrollView issue in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883591/listview-inside-a-scrollview-issue-in-android)

Comment: unless you propose an alternative that isn't an endlessly scrolling LinearLayout, please, don't tell me just not to use ListView. I want to achieve compatibility with iOS, where implementing the same mechanism was quite feasible